# Recent activity widget

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there any recent activity widget or a plugin that can be integrated into bootstrap template ? I need this for a web based information system so a user can see his activity at all times.

Comment: what research you did for this? Please share

Comment: I tried to find anything remotely close to what I need, but only thing that I could find were recent activity widgets for Facebook and Google+. Nothing more specific than that.

Comment: Recent activity where?

Comment: check this out : http://www.bootply.com/W79dvyuRnT